# PHP BETWEEN Clause usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql

PHP

I have having problem with my case, statements. I am trying to search books between 2 years but i am having trouble i can search one year using this code perfectly but trying for two is not working. I do understand i am more than likely going about this the wrong way to get desired result but any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Also i am getting ERROR Notice: Undefined variable: Year1 for the else part of the last case. Thanks.

If Year and Year1 have a value it should look bettwen the two years if Year just has a value just find books in that year.

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'searchscript.php';

$sql =  "SELECT DISTINCT bk.title AS Title, bk.bookid AS BookID, bk.year AS Year, bk.publisher AS Publisher, aut.authorname AS Author 
         FROM book bk 

         JOIN book_category bk_cat 
         ON bk_cat.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN categories cat 
         ON cat.id = bk_cat.category_id

         JOIN books_authors bk_aut 
         ON bk_aut.book_id = bk.bookid

         JOIN authors aut
         ON aut.id = bk_aut.author_id";

if(isset($_GET['searchInput'])){
$input = $_GET['searchInput'];
$input = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $input);
}
if (isset($input)){

    $getters = array();
    $queries = array();

    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
        if (!empty($temp)){
        if (!in_array($key, $getters)){
            $getters[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($getters)) {

        foreach($getters as $key => $value){
            ${$key} = $value;
            switch ($key) {
                case 'searchInput':
                    array_push($queries,"(bk.title LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.description LIKE '%$searchInput%' || bk.isbn LIKE '%$searchInput%' 
                    || bk.keywords LIKE '%$searchInput%' || aut.authorname LIKE '%$searchInput%')");
                break;
                case 'srch_publisher':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk.publisher = '$srch_publisher')");
                break;
                case 'srch_author':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk_aut.author_id = '$srch_author')");
                break;
                case 'srch_category':
                    array_push($queries, "(bk_cat.category_id = '$srch_category')");
                break;
                **case 'Year' && 'Year1':   
                    if("$Year1" ==""){
                        array_push($queries, "(bk.year = '$Year')");
                    } else {
                        array_push($queries, "(bk.year BETWEEN '$Year' AND '$Year1')");
                    }
                break;**
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($queries)){
    $sql .= " WHERE ";
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        if($i < count($queries)){
            $sql .= $query." AND ";
        } else {
            $sql .= $query;
        }   
        $i++;
    }
}
$sql .= " GROUP BY bk.title ORDER BY bk.title ASC";

}else{
    $sql .= " GROUP BY bk.title ORDER BY bk.title ASC";
}


$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
$tot_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
?>
```

Comment: You are getting the undefined $Year1 because there is nowhere in this code that $Year1 is being set to anything. Also, you did if("$year1" =="", instead of $year1==""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
foreach($getters as $key => $value)
    switch ($key) {
        case 'Year' && 'Year1':
            if("$Year1" ==""){
                array_push($queries, "(bk.year = '$Year')");
            } else {
                array_push($queries, "(bk.year BETWEEN '$Year' AND '$Year1')");
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

shows two issues:

1. `case` statements don't work this way. You can't use boolean operators the same way here like when using an `if()` statement. ([see manual](http://php.net/switch))
2. You cannot expect the iterator variable `$key` in `foreach($getters as $key=>$value)` hold both values at the same time, which you imply by saying `'Year' && 'Year1'`!

To solve those issues, you could do something like:

```
foreach($getters as $key => $value)
    switch ($key) {
        case 'Year':
            if($getters["Year1"] ==""){
                array_push($queries, "(bk.year = '{$value}')");
            } else {
                array_push($queries, "(bk.year BETWEEN '{$value}' AND '{$getters['Year1']}')");
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

In this case the block is executed when the `foreach($getters)` hits the key `'Year'`. The `if` statement now handles `'Year1'` correctly by accessing the value in the array directly instead of looking at the iterator variables.

Comment: Hey kaii,

i am looking to find if Year and Year1 have a value it should look for a book between the two years if Year just has a value just find books in that year. Do you know how i would layout my code to carryout that case.

Comment: @user3061378 updated my answer after reading your code more carefully

Comment: its saying still about Year and Year being undefined. any thoughts. thanks

Comment: @user3061378 just updated this answer again. had a typo in the code and created a new answer for a seperate issue you have

Comment: thank you Kaii, this code work perfect, and i will address the other issues you pointed out. But when i just select one year it says the if($getters["Year1"] ==""){ <<< Year1 is undefined but it still works

Comment: Write `if(isset($getters["Year1"]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as a seperate answer

**Your code shows severe security flaws which should be fixed!**

Excerpt:

```
// 1. happily copies all GET variables into an array
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $getters[$key] = $value;
}

if (!empty($getters)) {
    foreach($getters as $key => $value) {
        // 2. happily assings any PHP variable in the current scope to almost 
        //    unfiltered input from a malicious user
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
}

// any variable read after this point can not be trusted because
// the value might be manipulated by a malicious user!
```

**Also, SQL injection** all over the place! i won't repeat that SQL injection story again. See related questions!